# (Windows 7 Aero) Window titles show up bold

Tags: windows-7, aero

Here's the problem. I accidentally switched the theme to Classic (don't ask), and when I switched back, all windows have bold titles.

[image]

In the image, the top one is how it should be and the bottom is how it looks here. (I got the top image online)

Any proposals on how to fix this? Does this happen frequently?

Answer (score 3):

Open the start menu and type **Glass color**.  That should give you the Control Panel applet to change the color of the borders. Click **Advanced** and check that the font isn't** bolded**.

Edit:

[image: Start Menu]
[image]

Comment: I don't see any 'advanced' button on any of the applets... Can you specify its name?

Comment: I added pictures.

Comment: I don't understand why you have drawn a small yacht above `Type`

Comment: Looks more like a cutter to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the **Active Title Bar**'s font settings under the `Window Color and Appearance` dialog.

1. Open the **Control Panel** and **click** `Appearance and Personalization > Change the theme`.

   [image: Change the theme]
2. At the bottom of the **Personalization** window, **click** `Window Color`.

   [image: Window Color]
3. At the bottom of the **Window Color and Appearance** window, **click** `Advanced appearance settings...`.

   [image: Advanced appearance settings...]
4. A different **Window Color and Appearance** window pops up! **Select** `Active Title Bar` from the **Item** drop-down, and change the font's **Bold (B)** setting.

   [image: Active Title Bar]

   > **Note**: This window can also be accessed by launching the `Change window colors and metrics` shortcut from the **Start Menu**.
   >
   > [image: Change window colors and metrics]
5. **Click** `OK` to save.